# How do you Import data from a Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

How to take the first cell of a Google spreadsheet and output it as a string with JavaScript to an HTML document?

I have an HTML document labeled: "Website.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <script>
          var textDisplay = Some code to import spreadsheet cell text;
          document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = textDisplay;
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <p id="display"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and another file in the same folder labeled: "Spreadsheet.xcel" (or whatever file type that is). The first cell contains the text: "Hello".

How do I make the text in the spreadsheet import into the JavaScript of the HTML document?

Comment: Easiest would be something like `="var text = "'" & A1 & "';"`

Comment: How? Meaning I have a javascript code in an html doc called "Website" in a folder. In the same folder I have another file called "spreadsheet.excel" or whatever file type that is. How do I import it

Comment: You need to update your question with more detail if you really want usable answers. What server-side platform you're using would be a good start, but don't limit yourself to just that...

Comment: Ok I will update it and please take a look. I thank you for your help!

Comment: Still lacking needed details.  Where are these files - on your local machine/on a web server/somewhere else?  What event triggers this extraction?  What language/platform do you want to use to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your solution will depend on your data source; you included [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet), so here's an answer about that. Just stating the obvious to start: A google spreadsheet would not be a file on your server, instead it would be in "the cloud" in a Google Drive.

You can retrieve contents of google spreadsheets from your javascript, and there are examples here in SO:

- [Getting value of a cell from google docs spreadsheet into javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885231/getting-value-of-a-cell-from-google-docs-spreadsheet-into-javascript)
- [Access Google-apps public spreadsheet via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924563/access-google-apps-public-spreadsheet-via-javascript)

Basic idea for retrieving one cell of data as a string:

- In Google Drive, create your spreadsheet.
- [Publish the spreadsheet](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37579), picking the range A1 for the first cell. You should be provided a URL like:

  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=SPREADSHEET_KEY&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv

#### Example

```js
function loadData() {
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadData()">Load Spreadsheet Data</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also see this as a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3GLFA/1/).

*Thanks to [GPSVisualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/examples/google_spreadsheet.html), who were kind enough to publish a public google spreadsheet I could use for this example.*

Comment: How do we query more than one cell per request?

Comment: @ayjay - just use a different range in the URL. The range needs to be contiguous. For A1:B2, say, you'd use `var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1:B2&output=csv";`.