# Accesing DOM elements through document.X

Tags: javascript, dom

Where can I see more about this? I thought that you had to do `document.getElementById` always for interacting with an element.

source ([Getting data from Google docs into Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420907/getting-data-from-google-docs-into-javascript))

> So consider this JavaScript:

```
function Data(response) {
  document.Team.tName.value = response.feed.entry[0].gs$cell.$t; // HERE !
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="teams.js" >
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>             
    <form name="Team">
    <tr>                
        <td>
        <input  size="19"  name="tName" readonly >
        </td>               
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/18WEeF3d9pJWYK1sheNHgc0KOi845cjyZgJ8x6TVisFM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=Data&range=A1"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are a handful of ways other than just `.getElementById` that are officially supported, including `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: The functionality you've found here where you can reference a named element at `document[name]` is a shorthand commonly used by tutorials, but it isn't officially supported

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement Using form name and element names has been around since the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Use the `document.querySelector`:

```
function Data(response) {
  document.querySelector('[name=tName]').value = response.feed.entry[0].gs$cell.$t; 
}
```

---

#### `document.querySelector`

> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

---

#### `document.querySelector('[name=tName]')`

This will select the element with the attribute `name` and the value `tName`

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have mentioned, there are a few ways to access DOM elements.

If you're just looking at accessing form elements, take a look at [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) (MDN).

> The HTMLFormElement.elements property returns an HTMLFormControlsCollection (HTML 4 HTMLCollection) of all the form controls contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input elements which have a type attribute of image.

You'll get an neat collection of your form elements, which you can access either directly via their name attributes, or by iterating over the collection.

```
var formElements = document.querySelector('#some-form').elements;

console.log(formElements['some-form__input-yo'].value); // form element value

// OR

for (let element of formElements) {
   console.log(element.value); // form element value
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93nemsfq/