# Import Google Sheets cell data into simple HTML elements

Tags: html, google-apps-script, cell, google-sheets-api

First post here.

I'm looking to import cell data from Google Sheets into HTML elements. An example would be having a Google Sheet with item pricing where I could push the individual cell data into an HTML element.

I found these posts and it's what I'm looking for but I don't see a clear answer but it's most likely my lack of knowledge. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I'm not asking for a tutorial, just an expert's opinion so I don't end up researching something thats incorrect and waste a lot of time.

Thank You.

[Pull data from a google sheet and display as simple html text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389993/pull-data-from-a-google-sheet-and-display-as-simple-html-text)

[RSSHow can I pull just ONE cell of data at a time for Google Sheets to embed into my HTML content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353218/rsshow-can-i-pull-just-one-cell-of-data-at-a-time-for-google-sheets-to-embed-int)

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do, you can create a web app that will display the cell's contents, that's possible.

Comment: Is this an apps script webapp or calling the script from another webpage?

Comment: This would be calling the script from another webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use Sheets API then here's what it may look like.

I'll just give you a snippet to show this is doable.

[image]

First fetch the data from the spreadsheet using the [Reading a single range guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_a_single_range).

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/range
```

which I used in my XMLHttpRequest:

```
function fetchValues(){
         console.log("-----checkIfEmpty-----");
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('GET', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+myspreadsheetId+'/values/'+"Sheet1!"+A+":"+Z);
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myAccessToken);

          var arrayBuffer;
          var myArr;

         xhr.onload = function (oEvent) {
             arrayBuffer = xhr.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
             console.log("arrayBuffer "+ arrayBuffer);
             myArr = JSON.parse(arrayBuffer);

              for(var i = 0; i <= myArr.values.length; i++){
                      document.write(myArr.values[0][i] + "   ");
              }
         };
         xhr.send(null);
      }
```

Print it on the html page using `document.write`. I know this is a shabby job and there are proper ways of displaying data on the html page but I just wanted to show it's doable- from spreadhsheet to HTML page.

[image]