# Import data from Google Sheets not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sheets

**I would like to import data from Google spreadsheets to my website.**

Lets say, I have a page where there is a div-element with id ID "display", and inside the element there is a text "replace". So it would look like this:

```js
<div id="display">replace</div>

function loadData() {
  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=p_aHW5nOrj0VO2ZHTRRtqTQ&single=true&gid=0&range=A1&output=csv";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Now, I also have a Google spreadsheet document, which has a text "text-replaced", on the cell 1A.

So the question is, how do I import this cell to my website and replace the text "replace".

Any help?

I know this has been asked before, and I already tried this solution: ([How do you Import data from a Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485255/how-do-you-import-data-from-a-google-sheets)), but id didn't work.

Comment: what did not work?

Comment: Importing the data from Google sheets. There is the link I provided that goes to similar case and there is a solution as well, but for me it didn't work.

Comment: i suggest adding more about your case and what you tried before to make that work

Answer (score 0):

**So here is my HTML-code:**

```html
<div id="display">replace</div>
```

**And this is the JavaScript**. On the URL I tried to use the link you get when you click "publish to the web", comma-separated-values.

```js
function loadData() {
  var url="";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```