# Link cell value from Google Sheets to HTML page

Tags: google-sheets

I’m very new and basic to web design/code stuff.  All I can really do is basic html, not even CSS or Javascipt.  Problem tutorials I have read are also very confusing. So I’m hoping someone can help:

In essence here what I am trying to do is:
I want my website to always show the value (no formatting or anything, just the raw value) of cell A1 in my google sheet.  For example:

In google sheet I type in A1 “Hello123” and somehow link it to my website so it auto references that cell.
That way if I change Hello123 in cell A1 to “Hello456”
Then website will also now say “Hello456”

What html/java code/tutorial would allow me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What problem are you trying to solve with this exactly? If the google spreadsheet is not public, it is not exactly trivial to connect to it (you need to handle authentication and such). If the google spreadsheet is public, than probably, it is much easier to just show the spreadsheet to people. You can lock cells or make it read only from within the spreadsheet.

Comment: thanks. I have no problem making the sheet public for easier access, however I prefer not to direct ppl to the sheet but rather the website.  (I can explain why)

Comment: maybe this question will help you then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924563/access-google-apps-public-spreadsheet-via-javascript

Comment: unfortunately that post is from 2011 and I *think* google switched to a new "API" or something so that method appears it wont work.  I could be wrong

Comment: I know you have not yet learned Javascript, but there seems to be a Javascript library called Tabletop.j that allows your web-page to query Google sheets. Its link is here s https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop.git